# Get MassTransit message retries amount

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using Masstransit+RabbitMQ. One of the my consumers implements retry policy and I'm wondering if there any way to get message's retries amout once message is in the error queue?

Also I would like to know how MT counting retries because I didn't namage to find any related information in message's headers using RabbitMq server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can, in your consumer, use the following method to retry the retry attempt number.

```
consumeContext.GetRetryAttempt()
```

It should return > 0 if the current processing attempt is a retry.

Once the retry limit is reached, the next version of MassTransit (v6) will include a header in the error queue `MT-Fault-RetryCount` which will have the number of retries that were attempted. Also, `Fault<T>` messages will have that same header available.

Comment: Yes, but where this data is stored? In the message's header or somewhere in the middleware?

Comment: It's maintained in the middleware payload during message processing. It isn't persisted anywhere.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson: Haven't tried that with RabbitMQ, but with Azure Service Bus or in-memory transports the return value is always 0. Is this a bug? A missing feature? Or does it work for you and I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi guys. Has anyone found a solution? I'm having the same problem. And I dont found anything about it.

Comment: You might ask on Discord, "same problem" is usually close but not enough. Also, it works properly with a recent version of MassTransit so that might be a consideration.