# Determine if message will be retried from observer context in MassTransit 3

Tags: c#, masstransit

I would like to track the number of message retries and redelivers that occur while using MassTransit 3. I have both retries and redeliveries configured:

```
config.UseDelayedRedelivery(r => r.Immediate(2));
config.UseRetry(r => r.Immediate(3));
```

I have set up a `IConsumeObserver` and a `IReceiveObserver` as described [here](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/observers.html). And I can inspect the `ConsumeContext`/`ReceiveContext` in  `PostConsume<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context)`/`PostReceive(ReceiveContext context)`.

But when inspecting the contexts I cannot see a difference between the context for a message which was consumed without exception and one that threw an exception during consumption and will be redelivered.

How can I, in the `PostConsume`, method of an `IConsumeObserver` or `IReceiveObserver` determine if `context` represents a message that will be redelivered or one that has completed sucesfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it. MassTransit keeps the redelivery count in the message headers, otherwise, it won't know when to stop redelivering, according to your policy.

If this line returns a non-zero (or not null, I am not sure) - you are dealing with a redelivered message.

```
context.Headers.Get(MessageHeaders.RedeliveryCount, default(int?)));
```

If your message is being retried (not redelivered), check this answer from Chris: [Get MassTransit message retries amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490149/get-masstransit-message-retries-amount?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks @Alexey. This is the solution we're using now to log metrics. But it's not quite what I'm looking for in terms of my question. The header only seems to be present on the PostConsume of the **redelivered** attempt. So this cannot be used to differentiate between an initial attempt at processing the message that failed and one that succeeded. Put another way, I don't want to know if the message **was** redelivered, I want to know if it **will be** redelivered.

Comment: It seems like there must be an observer for this https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/bc142b9a37c75cde773f9cca47a53a256a382b06/src/MassTransit/Pipeline/Filters/RedeliveryRetryFilter.cs#L72

Comment: No, that is only for retry. The scheduling happens at the end. But may be you can figure something from this line https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/bc142b9a37c75cde773f9cca47a53a256a382b06/src/MassTransit/Pipeline/Filters/RedeliveryRetryFilter.cs#L107

Comment: Looks like the receive observer will get a Consumed called with a special type of message https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/87b15fb5a5fdedc435388eeee46b87d825dedee2/src/MassTransit/Context/BaseReceiveContext.cs#L108

Comment: Awesome. I won't be able to look into that today. But I will tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

The consumer can influence whether or not a message will be redelivered, but it doesn't have full control or knowledge of it.
For example, everything succeeds on the consuming side, but it just takes too long, the publisher will retry and the consumer has no simple way to know that this will happen.

It's often best to design your application so that consuming the same message multiple times has the same effect as consuming it one time.

Additionally, you check the MessageId on consuming the message if you want to see if you've consumed it before.

The ConsumeContext also has a RetryCount, but I don't *believe* it's incremented until the next time the consumer runs.

Comment: Thanks @Doug. It sounds like the answer to my question is "you can't". I'll wait a bit to make sure nobody chimes in with, "actually you can check it like this" and then accept this as the answer.