# MassTransit - knowing when IConsumeObserver.ConsumeFault is being called in or out of a retry

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

We're using MassTransit's `IConsumeObserver` to note Faults on consumption.
This is in lieu of a service consuming all `Fault` events because we're using Azure Service Bus and this [doesn't support polymorphic messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050780/masstransit-subscribing-to-all-fault-events-on-the-bus)

As we've got retries configured, we've noted that the `ConsumeFault<T>()` block is being entered in *every* retry.

We're looking for a way to determine if we're in or out of a retry; enter [`GetRetryAttempt()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490149/get-masstransit-message-retries-amount).
Example of our usage:

```
public virtual async Task ConsumeFault<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context, Exception exception) where T : class
{
        if (context.GetRetryAttempt() <= 0)
        {
            await NotifyFault());
        }
}
```

We've observed (ha, ha) that `GetRetryAttempt()` is always equal to 0, as also pointed out in a [comment on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490149/get-masstransit-message-retries-amount)

Is there another way to determine when we're no longer retrying? Or another way to take some action iff retries have been exhausted?

Comment: Well, shoot, this isn't ideal - as the fault isn't published until the retries are exhausted, but the observer doesn't follow that same behavior. I'll have to think about this one. There is a retry observer, that is called when retries are exhausted.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson - will look in to the retry observer in the meantime. If `GetRetryAttempt()` behaved as expected, I suppose we would have a way to only take action when the retries are exhausted? Or, have I misunderstood its purpose?

Comment: The retryAttempt stuff is fixed in the develop branch, but the fix hasn't been released yet.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson - Just pulled 5.2.0, and the retryAttempt stuff still doesn't appear to be fixed in there? Is there an ETA?

Comment: THis https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/a36e1d3e520f35bd13657ad29fadaeebb61b3255

Comment: And this https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/6de3b1741a52e905ee6eb5f78e995176e58f4ab7

Comment: Do you have an actual test case that shows the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson - yes. Sorry for the delay in doing this. Have put it on github here:
https://github.com/johncyril/MassTransit_RetryBugReproduction Happy to provide my ASB namespace and key privately if necessary

Comment: MassTransit is a pipeline, and order matters. The retry needs to be added before the consumer is added: https://github.com/johncyril/MassTransit_RetryBugReproduction/blob/master/MassTransitTestFailureNotification/Infrastructure/BusFactory.cs#L62

Comment: issue submitted to your example: https://github.com/johncyril/MassTransit_RetryBugReproduction/issues/1

Comment: Thanks for your pointers there. Much obliged. I'll write up an answer for completeness on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Chris Patterson [here](https://github.com/johncyril/MassTransit_RetryBugReproduction/issues/1)

The following needs to be taken into account

1. The .UseMessageRetry() needs to be on the endpoint configurator (ec), not the bus configurator.
2. UseMessageRetry also needs to be before the consumer configuration line.

e.g:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(
                sbc =>
                {
                    var host = ConfigureServiceBus(servicePath, sbc);
                    sbc.SubscriptionEndpoint<T>(host, subscriptionName, ec =>
                    {
                        ec.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[RetryConfigConstants.ServiceBusRetryCount]), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[RetryConfigConstants.ServiceBusRetryInterval]))));
                        ec.Consumer<EventConsumer<T>>(context);
                        if (timeToLive != default(TimeSpan))
                        {
                            ec.AutoDeleteOnIdle = timeToLive;
                        }                           
                    });
                })
```

Lastly, I discovered a bug in my own code w.r.t consumer registration in *autofac*. My IBus instance was registered with SingleInstance, as opposed to InstancePerLifetimeScope (which is how my subscriber and observer were registered)